Visual Studio: Can we show references count on field initialization?
Visual Studio 2022  Version17.8.6

The screenshot shows that references count show on method, class, property initialization.
Can we show references count on field initialization?

If yes, how to do that?
If not, why not?

I searched in CodeLens but didn't find anything

